# Set svn keywords recursively on *.cpp and *.h files

Tags: svn, svn-propset, version-control-keywords

I need to set from command line (cmd or powershell) some svn keywords recursively on **ALL** .h and .cpp files. How can I do it? I tried

```
svn propset svn:keywords "My keywords" -R *.cpp *.h
```

without success, it says me:

> svn: warning: '.cpp' is not under version control
>
> svn: warning: '.h' is not under version control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I used [THIS](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/setting-svnkeywords-for-specific-files-with-windows-powershell-or-grep-with-powershell/) script for powershell

Answer (score 2):

You can use [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) and [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) for the purpose:

```
find . -name \*.cpp -or -name \*.h -print0 | xargs -0 svn propset svn:keywords "My keywords"
```

**EDIT** I see that you are on Windows. I don't know what's the find/xargs equivalent on windows but you could install Cygwin and get these utilities, if needed.